# conditions required to make an object polymorphic

Tags: java

What's the difference between a normal object and a polymorphic object in java?

Can someone please explain to me

1. why Currentaccounts object is polymorphic object or not? if so why?
2. can someone explain the conditions required to implement polymorphic object?
3. what is needed to be done to transfer a non polymorphic object to a polymorphic object?

Code sample:

```
private CurrentAccount CurrentAccounts;
private ISAAccount ISAAccounts;
private SavingAccount SavingAccounts;
public ArrayList<Account> Accounts;

public Customer() {
    Filename = "CustomerDetails.txt";
    FirstName = "";
    LastName = "";
    DOB = "01/01/1900";

    HomeAddress = new IAddress();
    CurrentAccounts = new CurrentAccount(this);
    ISAAccounts = new ISAAccount(this);
    SavingAccounts = new SavingAccount(this);

    Accounts = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: A couple of things: 1) post your code in text format, not as an image, 2) provide the complete code of your classes.

Comment: Note, there are 2 type of Polymorphism, Compile-time and Runtime (or Static and Dynamic respectively), 'true' polymorphism is the Runtime form and relates to method *overriding* (whereas compile-time/static 'polymorphism' relates to method *overloading*).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza my code is up now

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism is the ability of something to have many forms. Or in other words, you can have a class car, which is the general blueprint for all other cars. And then you could have a corvette. Which is still a car, but it also has its own specific characteristics, nonetheless it is still a car, so it could "INHERIT" certain traits from the Car class, while still being its own version of a car. id recommend having a look at some OOP(Object Oriented Programming) lessons to better clarify this for you as it has to do with a lot of different things. Understanding the basics of what Polymorphism and Inheritance are will help you to put everything together in your head.

Answer (score -2):

All object in Java all polymorphic by default. There is no keyword for that like in others languages like "virtual". 
So you need nothing to create polymorphic object :)

For example you can have smth like that:

```
interface Account {}


class CurrentAccounts implements Account {}
class IsAAccounts implements Account {}
class SavingAccounts implements Account {}
```

so now, you can add to your list

```
List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList();
```

all these classes.

Comment: If you declare a class `final` then no other class can extend it, so it won't be polymorphic.

Comment: you know in java is something called interface? :) final class can implements interfaces. So your comment kind of weird.

Comment: Inheritance != polymorphism.

Comment: @Moler sure, but if you define `public final class MyClass implements SomeInterface { /* ... */ }`, then `MyClass` cannot be extended, so that class is not polymorphic. I don't know what's weird...